# Pass value from view to controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Background: I have a controller -- Recipes, which generates all the recipes I have in the db and I can click one to see the detail info of the certain recipe. In the certain recipe view, I also pass all the comments this recipe has received. Below the comments info I can just make new comments upon this recipe.

Here is the question: I of course have the recipe id ----- @recipe.id. When I fill all the comment information and click submit button, this form will post to another controller -- Comments. But I just don't know how to pass the recipe id I have in this page to the Comments controller.

Recipe Controller:

```
def show
  #For getting the ingredient info from ingredient set
  @ingredientset=IngredientSet.where("recipeid=?",set_recipe.id)

  @ingredients = Array.new()
  i=0

  @ingredientset.each do |set|
    @ingredients[i]=Ingredient.find(set.ingredientid)
    i+=1
  end
```

Recipe Information View:(I only show the part for making the comment)

```
<!--for adding a new comment-->
<div id="add_comment">    
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>

<% hidden_field .....%> 
<!--Here I want to pass the @recipe.id value into the comment controller-->
<!--But I dont know should I use hidden_field or something else-->
<!--I was .net MVC developer, so I only know something like @html.hiddenfor() or @ViewBag.xxx stuff-->

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :comment %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :comment %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Also I don't know how to even get the value in the Comments controller since I'm totally new in ruby on rails.

Here is the Comments controller:

```
def create
@comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
@comment.recipeid = params[:recipeid])
end
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it does sound like a [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field) tag is what you want.

So, in your form, you'd add:

`f.hidden_field :recipeid, <value>`

Personally, if I use a `hidden_field` tag, I look for another way to do this, since those tags can easily be modified in the DOM before form submission.  I'd look to see if there's a way to do this in your controller itself.

Comment: Yes I tried but it gave the error:undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: It worked after trying the way you suggested but when I tried to get the value in the Comments controller, I saw the paramter is like this : "recipeid"=>{"1"=>""}. I don't know why and how to make it work now?

Comment: Ok, I just figured out how. Because I didn't add the f before the hidden_field tag which causes rails couldn't determine which object is this parameter belonging to. Now it works totally fine. Thank you very much!